# set target blank on link inside CKEditor of liferay

Tags: ckeditor, liferay

I want to set target blank for "link" inside CKEditor of Liferay.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can view ckeditor content as source and edit anchor tag

Comment: @PankajKathiriya it would be helpful if you explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to provide a link in the `content` portion of the ckeditor and want to change how the link behaves.

So here is a simple illustration from the web-content portlet:

1. Normal View of the Editor, shows how you can enter a link

   [image: How the WYSIWYG view or normal view looks]
2. Source view of the Editor, shows how you can modify the behaviour of the link

   [image: How the source view looks]

Hope this helps and this is what you meant.

Comment: But everythime when we add a link inside CKEditor we have to change the html manually. my goal is to change the behaviour of CKEditor!

Comment: Should we have to create ext plugin for this changes. as far i know it uses the XhtmlTranslator class. should i have to override our custom class?

Comment: Your questions doesn't say so. Anyways, you can create a hook which will override the JSP and JS files inside FCKEditor to achieve this. This is definitely doable with a hook I would have to dig into the code to find out what to change so I leave it upto you :)

Comment: If you want you can provide an answer to the question and then mark it. So that other's know which file you changed and it will help them. Thanks

Comment: about this issue i had to open link posted in wiki on another browser. So, i use
<aui:script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wiki-body a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
</aui:script>

Answer (score 1):

The new ckeditor5 has config property.
I was using the ckeditor for react and all I had to do was to add this

```
<CKEditor
  data={q.explanation}
  config={
   {
     link: {
       addTargetToExternalLinks: true
     }
   }
  }
  height="500"
  editor={ClassicEditor}
/>
```

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_link_link-LinkConfig.html#member-addTargetToExternalLinks

Answer (score 0):

To make default:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function( ev ){
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if ( dialogName == 'link' ){
        // Get a reference to the "Target" tab.
                var targetTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'target' ); 
                // Set the default value for the target field.
                var targetField = targetTab.get( 'linkTargetType' );
                targetField['default'] = '_blank';
         }
}
```

reference: http://witmax.cn/ckeditor-link-target.html